# How to reorder elements so first element is on the right and second element on the left?

Tags: html, css

Is there a way through CSS where I can display the add to cart button first and then the select drop down second? At the moment the select drop down is on the left and add to cart on the right but I want it other way round.

```
<div class="woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart variations_button woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart-enabled">
  <div class="quantity">
<select name="quantity">
      <option value="1" selected="”>1</option></select>
        <button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt">Add to Cart</button>
</div>
</div>

.archive .woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart {
display: flex;
flex-flow: row nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you make `.quantity` a Flexbox "parent", you can use the [Flexbox (child) property `order`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order) to reorder elements.

```
.quantity { 
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.quantity select {
  order: 2;
}
.quantity button {
  order: 1;
}
```

```css
.quantity { 
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.quantity select {
  order: 2;
}
.quantity button {
  order: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart variations_button woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart-enabled">
  <div class="quantity">
    <select name="quantity">
      <option value="1" selected="">1</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt">Add to Cart</button>
  </div>
</div>
```